# Error in naming Eloquent model. "Call to undefined method"

Tags: laravel, eloquent

"Mrp" is an Eloquent model defined as follows.

```
 <?php

    class Mrp extends Eloquent {
       protected $guarded = array();
       protected $softDelete = true;
       public static $rules = array();
       protected $table = 'mrps';

       public function product()
       {
          return this->bleongsTo('Product');
       }
     }
```

The following code produces error.

```
 Mrp::create(array('mrp'=>100, 'product_id'=>3));
```

And the error is

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
 Call to undefined method Mrp::create()
```

**Edit**

When used names other than "Mrp", it works. So it must be something with the name. Is "Mrp" a reserved word by Laravel?

Comment: What is your file called? Remove the file and create it again with the same content and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating model object first:

```
$object = new Mrp();
$object->create(array('mrp'=>100, 'product_id'=>3));
```

You can also use Dependency injection in contructor